# MariaDB- Can i create a unique key requirement if the dates are the same but allow it if they are different?

Tags: mariadb, unique-constraint

I am trying to create an unique index on barcode and date. Is it possible to have `make barcode unique unless date is different than inserted row's (date) being inserted`?
I created a unique index on the barcode, but sometimes labels get reprinted on accident or the sequences reset after time passes and the three digit limit of 999 occurs.

```
    [barcode]          [date]            what i want to happen
=========================================================
    1234567999        2022-12-01          be entered into database
    1234567001        2022-12-02          be entered into database
    1234567999        2023-12-01          be entered into database
    1234567001        2023-12-02          be entered into database
    1234567999        2023-12-01          fail as duplicate
```

How do I go about making this happen in Maria DB?

Comment: `UNIQUE(barcode, date)` -- Wouldn't this work?  If not, please provide an example.

Comment: @RickJames can you submit this as an answer so i can mark this as correct. new to db's as an admin. You got me where I needed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have described needs a "composite" index:

```
UNIQUE(barcode, date)
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL a tuple is made of several items written (a,b,c...). For example (last_name,first_name) or (date,barcode).

Consider two tuples (date1,barcode1) and (date2,barcode2).

(date1,barcode1) = (date2,barcode2) if and only if all the items of tuple1 are equal to the corresponding items of tuple2. In this case, date1=date2 and barcode1=barcode2.

So if you create a UNIQUE constraint on (date,barcode), it's the whole tuple that is unique: there can be only one row with specific values of (date,barcode). I guess this corresponds to what you want.

Note that NULL means unknown, and NULL is not equal to NULL, so even if you set a UNIQUE constraint on (a,b), you can have as many rows with (a,NULL) and the same value of a.

Now you could also use UNIQUE(barcode,date) and that would do the exact same thing, so you have to choose which one.

UNIQUE is implemented as a special type of index, in this case a 2-column index, on the same columns and in the same order. Since an index on (a,b,c...) can also be used as an index on (a) and (a,b), you can choose the column order in your unique constraint to make the most of the "free" index. So if you already had an index on (date) and create an UNIQUE(date,barcode) you can drop the first index since the UNIQUE index already covers that column, it'll save some resources.

Personally I'd use UNIQUE(barcode,date) since that optimizes:

- WHERE barcode=... ORDER BY date
- WHERE barcode=... AND date=...
- WHERE barcode=... AND date BETWEEN...

...then if you had an index on barcode you can drop it. TAn index on date is also needed.

The other case, (date,barcode) would be less useful because you probably aren't going to use BETWEEN or ORDER BY on barcode.